# version column does not get increased with JPA (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, locking, jpa-2.0

I have the following Entity structure:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    private int _version;

    public BaseEntity() {
    }

    @Version
    @Column(name = "oplock", nullable = false)
    private int getVersion() {
        return _version;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setVersion(final int version) {
        _version = version;
    }
    //some other code goes here....

}
```

the concrete Entity:

```
@Table(name="my_table", schema="public", 
    uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"username", "attribute"})
)
public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String attribute;
    private String op;
    private String value;

    public MyEntity() {
    }
    //some code goes here ....

}
```

Now, I select from the database an entity of `MyEntity` type, lock it with `entityManager.lock(myEntityInstance, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);`, modify it, and persist modifications. The thing that I expect to get is to have `oplock` column's value incremented (`oplock` is the version column), but it is untouched.

**Question:** Does it behave right or am I missing something? I think the right behavior would be that the `oplock`'s value would be incremented.

---

Edit: After I switched from `hibernate` 3.6 to `hibernate` 4.1, I still get the same behavior.

Comment: What version of hibernate do you use?

Comment: @PeterRader I use 3.6.10 hibernate version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem:

I put only `@MappedSuperclass` annotation above `BaseEntity` class. For more details you can read [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e3498).